# Relational DB - separate joined tables

Tags: python, sql, database, join

Is there any way to join tables from a relational database and then separate them again ?

I'm working on a project that involves modifying the data after having joined them. Unfortunately, modifying the data bejore the join is not an option. I would then want to separate the data according to the original schema.

I'm stuck at the separating part. I have metadata (python dictionary) with the information on the tables (primary keys, foreign keys, fields, etc.).

I'm working with python. So, if you have a solution in python, it would be greatly appretiated. If an SQL solution works, that also helps.

Edit : Perhaps the question was unclear. To summarize I would like to create a new database with an identical schema to the old one. I do not want to make any modifications to the original database. The data that makes up the new database must originally be in a single table (result of a join of the old tables) as the operations that need to be run must be run on a single table and I cannot run these operations on invidual tables as the outcome will not be as desired.

I would like to know if this is possible and, if so, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is unclear. JOIN doesn't modify the database tables. `modifying the data bejore the join is not an option.` why? And why would you need to *modify* what sounds  like query results? Don't you mean *read* them?

Comment: I do not want to modify the original database tables but I want new tables with the modified data and the same schema. That is why the correct word is "modify" and not "read".
I cannot create the tables individually and then modify them because the operations that need to be run require the cross-table data to be in a single table. 
Perhaps it is more clear if I say : "create a new table from the query results then separate that new table with respect to the original schema."